# Fit when some data are missing

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have:

```
c1 = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

c2 = {-23, -19, -15, -11, -7, -3, 1, 5, 9, 13, 17};

data = Transpose[{c1, c2}]

(* {{-5, -23}, {-4, -19}, {-3, -15}, {-2, -11}, {-1, -7}, 
    {0, -3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 13}, {5, 17}} *)
```

I would like to fit the data with:

```
model = a + b*x;
```

The result is:

```
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b}, x] 

{a -> -3., b -> 4.}
```

Now, what happens if some data of `c2` are missing?

```
c1 = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

c2 = {-23, , -15, -11, , -3, 1, 5, , 13, 17};

data = Transpose[{c1, c2}]

(* {{-5, -23}, {-4, Null}, {-3, -15}, {-2, -11}, {-1, Null}, 
    {0, -3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, Null}, {4, 13}, {5, 17}} *)
```

The fit yields then:

```
model = a + b*x;

fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b}, x] 

(* {a -> 0.301511 (-4.82418 + 0.904534 Null), 
    b -> 0.0953463 (31.4643 - 0.190693 Null)} *)
```

which is not what I want, since:

[image]

How can this be solved?

Comment: Just only try to fit to non-Null data points, use `data = Select[Transpose[{c1, c2}], NumericQ[#[[2]]] &]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should simply remove the terms with the missing data:

```
data = {{-5, -23}, {-4, Null}, {-3, -15}, {-2, -11}, {-1, 
Null}, {0, -3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, Null}, {4, 13}, {5, 
17}} /. {x_, y_} /; y == Null -> Nothing

(* {{-5, -23}, {-3, -15}, {-2, -11}, {0, -3}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}, {4, 
  13}, {5, 17}}   *)
```

Then fitting

```
 model = a + b*x;
FindFit[data, model, {a, b}, x]
```

yields exactly the same result:

```
{a -> -3., b -> 4.}
```

Have fun!